# disconnect() is deprecated: Please use the shouldEstablishDirectChannel property instead

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When looking at the disconnect() method and it's description it says the following in the docs

> Disconnect the current FIRMessaging data connection. This stops any attempts to connect to FIRMessaging. Calling this on an already disconnected client is a no-op.

But looking at the shouldEstablishDirectChannel property

> When set to YES, Firebase Messaging will automatically establish a socket-based, direct channel to the FCM server. You only need to enable this if you are sending upstream messages or receiving non-APNS, data-only messages in foregrounded apps. Default is NO.

It seems that they don't do exactly the same thing, but I might be wrong. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 24):

So what i found is this.

the disconnect()  and the connect() functions are no longer needed. You can just turn the bolean to true and it makes the connection.

I was bonking my head against the wall because if that error warning.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
```

to:

```
        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
```

and the same goes for the connect by turning the bolean to true. since there is now where explaining this change i tought i should awnser. I also tested this on a device and i am still reciving push notifications.

Comment: and what about connect method with handler ?

Comment: @SujayUN you can get the state by the triggered notification which is NSNotification.Name.MessagingConnectionStateChanged

Comment: @Khunshan I don't have idea how to do that. If u can explain in details and replay as an answer, will be very helpful.

Comment: Not only are they no longer needed, they've been removed in 6.0.0. Attempting to call them will result in a crash